# Different types of user registration with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, registration

I use Spring Boot and i created a User class and a Lawyer class that inherits User
I want to switch between the type of user using a registration form on front end
Is the right way to duplicate the user's registration service and controller and do the same for lawyer resulting in two different endpoints ?
api/register/user
api/register/lawyer
Any help would be much appreciated,thank you!

I used the method I said above so far

Comment: You will define a field for user types (enum would be nice). Then ui side, you will show a page depends on which type user chose.

Comment: Could you show an example of implementation?Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should define a field for user types (enum would be nice). Then ui side, you will show a page depends on which type user chose.
User save endpoint should be like this :

```
@PostMapping
  public void save(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.save(lawyer);
}
```

Enum class:

```
enum User {
  User,
  Lawyer
}
```